# Using this.$set as a computed/watched property in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Until now I've been using `this.$set` to change the value of one getter from vuex store using a state variable (from vuex store).

So when my component was mounted I changed that data with the other value:

```
mounted () {
   this.$set(this.linedata[0].chartOptions.xAxis,"categories",this.dates)
}
```

Now I decided that I need to update this data whenever `this.dates` variable changes but putting 
using:

```
computed: {
   this.$set(this.linedata[0].chartOptions.xAxis,"categories",this.dates) 
}
```

does not work, so I wonder what I could do to set the value of first variable whenver second one changes?

EDIT:
So to be clear `this.dates` value is updated after api call is finish and response is received. So when this changes I need to update the `this.linedata[0].chartOptions.xAxis.categories` value with new value of `this.dates`

Comment: If you are using Vuex, why are you not using actions and mutations to set the data you need? What's your use case?

Comment: Well I need something to watch for change in one of the vuex state values... I dont think actions/mutations solve it

Comment: Rule no. 1 "only mutation modifies the state" Think about using `$set` in a mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of computed you should use the **watch** section like this:

```
watch: {
   dates (newValue, oldValue) {
     this.$set(this.linedata[0].chartOptions.xAxis,"categories",this.dates)
   }
}
```

Comment: I get error that  newValue is defined but never used

Comment: you can remove both params if you don't use them.